# The dinner is cooked. vs. The dinner is ready

Tags: interpretation

> The dinner is cooked. (A)

> The dinner is ready. (B)

There could be any difference? I like (B). (A) is not friendly/familiar with me and makes me analyze and interprete the status of the dinner: not directly forms the image of the meaning.

What's the real meaning of (A)? (A) means the dinner is ready now? It's done already?

Comment: It's not a question of meaning. It's a question of context. Two chefs responsible for preparing dinner would probably use the first in conversation. A host/ess would use the second in speaking to guests, before inviting them to the table.

Comment: Thx. (A) means the dinner is already done?

Comment: It means that whatever food is in the oven is ready to be eaten.

Comment: The dinner has been cooked for a sufficient time and is therefore ready to be eaten.

Comment: Why don't you use perfect tense like: The dinner has been cooked. Or simple past: The dinner was cooked. I think present perfect or simple past gives more clear meaning.

Comment: I now think 'cooked' is closer to an adjective than a past participle forming a passive voice.

Comment: Not all dinners require cooking.  A cold salad could be **ready** without being **cooked**.

Comment: The tense was supplied by you! _Cooked_ in _The dinner has been cooked_ is a verb, but in _The dinner is cooked_ it is an adjective describing the state the food is in.